# Json serializing changing DataTime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, autorest

I am currently calling a rest api from a .net MVC5 website and used AutoRest (0.17.3) to generate the code from the rest api swagger.json.

It is all working perfectly but it is changing the datetime of one of the fields by an hour when I use the put method. I have found the place in the auto-generated code that is causing the issue:

```
   _requestContent = Microsoft.Rest.Serialization.SafeJsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, this.SerializationSettings);
```

It seems to be changing the time when it serializes the object to Json.

I have set the culture in the web.config, but we are still having the same issue.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? If possible globally, so we do not have to change the auto-generated code. Otherwise we would have to remember to make this change everytime we re-generate the code.

Many thanks

Andy

Comment: It's a time zone issue.  All times on the server should be handled as UTC, and converted into local time in the browser.  The serializer is probably automatically converting the time to UTC during serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your data time value specified as local time (has property `Kind` equals to `DateTimeKind.Local`). That is why this value is serialized with time change. If you change this property to `DateTimeKind.Utc`, data value will be serialized without changing. See example:

```
var local = DateTime.Now;
var utc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(local, DateTimeKind.Utc);

var _requestContentLocal = Microsoft.Rest.Serialization.SafeJsonConvert.SerializeObject(local);
var _requestContentUTC = Microsoft.Rest.Serialization.SafeJsonConvert.SerializeObject(utc);

_requestContentLocal    "\"2017-06-29T18:19:32.6704837+03:00\"" 
_requestContentUTC  "\"2017-06-29T18:19:32.6704837Z\""
```